# In tab layout fragments not showing their layout in androidX

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a tab layout in which I have included five fragments, but when i click on tabs, the fragments layout is not showed. In my adapter I've extended FragmentPagerAdapter which has FragmentManager and a variable behaviour.

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull fm:FragmentManager, behaviour:Int):
    FragmentPagerAdapter(fm, behaviour) {

    private val tabs:Array<Fragment> = arrayOf(
        Category1Fragment(),
        Category2Fragment(),
        Category3Fragment(),
        Category4Fragment(),
        Category5Fragment()
    )

    @NonNull
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return tabs[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return tabs.size
    }

    @Nullable
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> "Bags"
            1 -> "Watches"
            2 -> "Shoes"
            3 -> "Glasses"
            4 -> "Audio"
            else -> null
        }
    }
}
```

and in my activity I've called adapter through viewpager, but when I debug is telling me that adapter is null, here's my activity code:

```
val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, tab_layout.selectedTabPosition)
val viewPager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.view_pager)
viewPager.adapter = adapter
val tab = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tab_layout)
tab.setupWithViewPager(view_pager)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

tab.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabReselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }

            override fun onTabSelected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                viewPager.currentItem = tab.selectedTabPosition
            }

})
```

In the previous versions of android I did the same, but in androidX things are something different. I tried also to use ViewPager2, but it was confusing. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do u understand fragments are not shown ? `Layout are transparent by default` did u use any colors ?  Also u can use synthetic directly instead of `findViewById()` i.e, `view_pager`

Comment: @SantanuSur No, I don;t use any color. The content in fragments is not showing.